# vkCreateGraphicsPipelines causes segv

Tags: c#, c++, vulkan

I've been following a coding stream and translating to c# as I go.

When I try to create a VkPipeline with the vkCreateGraphicsPipelines function the program crashes because of a segv.

I have the gdb backtrace but I don't know how to interpret it.

```
Thread 1 "VulkanRen" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff56fa1cad in StatelessValidation::validate_struct_type_array<VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo> (count_required_vuid=0x7fff5715b558 "VUID-vkCreateGraphicsPipelines-createInfoCount-arraylength", 
    param_vuid=0x7fff5715bb80 "VUID-vkCreateGraphicsPipelines-pCreateInfos-parameter", stype_vuid=0x7fff57054bc0 "VUID-VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo-sType-sType", arrayRequired=true, countRequired=true, 
    sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO, array=0xf1c038196785ba00, count=<optimized out>, sTypeName=0x7fff571a67a0 "VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO", arrayName=..., countName=..., 
    apiName=0x7fff571a052c "vkCreateGraphicsPipelines", this=<optimized out>) at /root/sdk-build/1.1.121.1/source/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/layers/stateless_validation.h:318
318 /root/sdk-build/1.1.121.1/source/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/layers/stateless_validation.h: No such file or directory.
Missing separate debuginfos, use: dnf debuginfo-install dotnet-hostfxr-3.0-3.0.0-1.x86_64 dotnet-runtime-3.0-3.0.0-1.x86_64
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00007fff56fa1cad in StatelessValidation::validate_struct_type_array<VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo> (count_required_vuid=0x7fff5715b558 "VUID-vkCreateGraphicsPipelines-createInfoCount-arraylength", 
    param_vuid=0x7fff5715bb80 "VUID-vkCreateGraphicsPipelines-pCreateInfos-parameter", stype_vuid=0x7fff57054bc0 "VUID-VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo-sType-sType", arrayRequired=true, countRequired=true, 
    sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO, array=0xf1c038196785ba00, count=<optimized out>, sTypeName=0x7fff571a67a0 "VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO", arrayName=..., countName=..., 
    apiName=0x7fff571a052c "vkCreateGraphicsPipelines", this=<optimized out>) at /root/sdk-build/1.1.121.1/source/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/layers/stateless_validation.h:318
#1  StatelessValidation::PreCallValidateCreateGraphicsPipelines (this=<optimized out>, device=<optimized out>, pipelineCache=<optimized out>, createInfoCount=<optimized out>, pCreateInfos=<optimized out>, pAllocator=<optimized out>, 
    pPipelines=0x7fffffffbfc8) at /root/sdk-build/1.1.121.1/source/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/layers/generated/parameter_validation.cpp:3086
#2  0x00007fff56ebc643 in ValidationObject::PreCallValidateCreateGraphicsPipelines (cgpl_state=<optimized out>, pPipelines=0x7fffffffbfc8, pAllocator=<optimized out>, pCreateInfos=<optimized out>, createInfoCount=<optimized out>, 
    pipelineCache=<optimized out>, device=<optimized out>, this=0x1248650) at /root/sdk-build/1.1.121.1/source/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/layers/generated/chassis.h:3688
#3  vulkan_layer_chassis::CreateGraphicsPipelines (device=<optimized out>, pipelineCache=<optimized out>, createInfoCount=<optimized out>, pCreateInfos=<optimized out>, pAllocator=<optimized out>, pPipelines=0x7fffffffbfc8)
    at /root/sdk-build/1.1.121.1/source/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/layers/generated/chassis.cpp:749
#4  0x00007fff5697b1f7 in DispatchCreateGraphicsPipelines (device=device@entry=0xd846d0, pipelineCache=pipelineCache@entry=0x0, createInfoCount=createInfoCount@entry=1, pCreateInfos=0xf1c038196785ba00, pAllocator=pAllocator@entry=0x0, 
    pPipelines=pPipelines@entry=0x7fffffffbfc8) at /root/sdk-build/1.1.121.1/source/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/layers/generated/layer_chassis_dispatch.cpp:210
#5  0x00007fff568ee2b2 in vulkan_layer_chassis::CreateGraphicsPipelines (device=<optimized out>, pipelineCache=<optimized out>, createInfoCount=<optimized out>, pCreateInfos=<optimized out>, pAllocator=<optimized out>, 
    pPipelines=0x7fffffffbfc8) at /root/sdk-build/1.1.121.1/source/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/layers/generated/chassis.cpp:759
#6  0x00007fff7dcbf9bc in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

The crash seems to be happening inside the validation layers. Here is the function that causes the crash. This is c++.

```cpp
/**
* Validate an array of Vulkan structures
*
* Verify that required count and array parameters are not 0 or NULL.  If
* the array contains 1 or more structures, verify that each structure's
* sType field is set to the correct VkStructureType value.
*
* @param apiName Name of API call being validated.
* @param countName Name of count parameter.
* @param arrayName Name of array parameter.
* @param sTypeName Name of expected VkStructureType value.
* @param count Number of elements in the array.
* @param array Array to validate.
* @param sType VkStructureType for structure validation.
* @param countRequired The 'count' parameter may not be 0 when true.
* @param arrayRequired The 'array' parameter may not be NULL when true.
* @return Boolean value indicating that the call should be skipped.
*/
template <typename T>
bool validate_struct_type_array(const char *apiName, const ParameterName &countName, const ParameterName &arrayName,
                                    const char *sTypeName, uint32_t count, const T *array, VkStructureType sType,
                                    bool countRequired, bool arrayRequired, const char *stype_vuid, const char *param_vuid,
                                    const char *count_required_vuid) {
    bool skip_call = false;

    if ((count == 0) || (array == NULL)) {
        skip_call |= validate_array(apiName, countName, arrayName, count, &array, countRequired, arrayRequired,
                                        count_required_vuid, param_vuid);
    } else {
       // Verify that all structs in the array have the correct type
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            if (array[i].sType != sType) { //<-- This line causes segv
                skip_call |=
                    log_msg(report_data, VK_DEBUG_REPORT_ERROR_BIT_EXT, VK_DEBUG_REPORT_OBJECT_TYPE_UNKNOWN_EXT, 0, stype_vuid,
                                "%s: parameter %s[%d].sType must be %s", apiName, arrayName.get_name().c_str(), i, sTypeName);
            }
        }
    }

    return skip_call;
}
```

And here is my c# code:

```cs
static VkShaderModule LoadShader (VkDevice device, string path) {
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes (path);

    uint length = (uint) bytes.Length;

    VkShaderModuleCreateInfo pCreateInfo = VkShaderModuleCreateInfo.New ();
    pCreateInfo.codeSize = new UIntPtr (length);
    fixed (byte * ptr = & bytes[0])
    pCreateInfo.pCode = (uint * ) ptr;

    VkShaderModule shaderModule = new VkShaderModule ();
    Assert (vkCreateShaderModule (device, & pCreateInfo, null, & shaderModule));

    return shaderModule;
}
static VkPipelineLayout CreatePipelineLayout (VkDevice device) {
    VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pCreateInfo = VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo.New ();
    pCreateInfo.pushConstantRangeCount = 0;
    pCreateInfo.setLayoutCount = 0;

    VkPipelineLayout layout = VkPipelineLayout.Null;
    Assert (vkCreatePipelineLayout (device, & pCreateInfo, null, & layout));
    return layout;
}
static VkPipeline CreatePipeline (VkDevice device, VkPipelineCache pipelineCache, VkRenderPass renderPass,
    VkShaderModule vs, VkShaderModule fs, VkPipelineLayout layout) {

    VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pCreateInfo = VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo.New ();

    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo[] shaderStages = new VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo[2];
    shaderStages[0] = VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo.New ();
    shaderStages[0].flags = (uint) VkShaderStageFlags.Vertex;
    shaderStages[0].module = vs;
    byte[] vsFuncName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ("main" + char.MinValue);
    fixed (byte * ptr = & (vsFuncName[0]))
    shaderStages[0].pName = ptr;

    shaderStages[1] = VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo.New ();
    shaderStages[1].flags = (uint) VkShaderStageFlags.Fragment;
    shaderStages[1].module = vs;
    byte[] fsFuncName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes ("main" + char.MinValue);
    fixed (byte * ptr = & (fsFuncName[0]))
    shaderStages[1].pName = ptr;

    fixed (VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo * ptr = & (shaderStages[0]))
    pCreateInfo.pStages = ptr;
    pCreateInfo.stageCount = 2;

    VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo vertexInput = VkPipelineVertexInputStateCreateInfo.New ();
    pCreateInfo.pVertexInputState = & vertexInput;

    VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputAssembly = VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo.New ();
    inputAssembly.topology = VkPrimitiveTopology.TriangleList;
    pCreateInfo.pInputAssemblyState = & inputAssembly;

    VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewportState = VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo.New ();
    viewportState.viewportCount = 1;
    viewportState.scissorCount = 1;
    pCreateInfo.pViewportState = & viewportState;

    VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterizationState = VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo.New ();
    rasterizationState.lineWidth = 1;
    pCreateInfo.pRasterizationState = & rasterizationState;

    VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo multisampleState = VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo.New ();
    multisampleState.rasterizationSamples = VkSampleCountFlags.Count1;
    pCreateInfo.pMultisampleState = & multisampleState;

    VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo depthState = VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo.New ();
    pCreateInfo.pDepthStencilState = & depthState;

    VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState colourAttachment = new VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState ();
    colourAttachment.colorWriteMask = VkColorComponentFlags.R | VkColorComponentFlags.G | VkColorComponentFlags.B | VkColorComponentFlags.A;

    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colourState = VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo.New ();
    colourState.pAttachments = & colourAttachment;
    colourState.attachmentCount = 1;
    pCreateInfo.pColorBlendState = & colourState;

    VkDynamicState[] dynamicStates = new VkDynamicState[2];
    dynamicStates[0] = VkDynamicState.Viewport;
    dynamicStates[1] = VkDynamicState.Scissor;

    VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo dynamicState = VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo.New ();
    dynamicState.dynamicStateCount = (uint) dynamicStates.Length;
    fixed (VkDynamicState * ptr = & (dynamicStates[0]))
    dynamicState.pDynamicStates = ptr;
    pCreateInfo.pDynamicState = & dynamicState;

    pCreateInfo.layout = layout;
    pCreateInfo.renderPass = renderPass;

    VkPipeline pipeline = VkPipeline.Null;
    Assert (vkCreateGraphicsPipelines (device, 0, 1, & pCreateInfo, null, & pipeline));
    return pipeline;
}
```

Comment: Are you using C#, C++ or C? Also, what do your validation layers tell you?

Comment: I am using c# with a binding for the c++ libraries. The validation layers say absolutely nothing. The segv happens inside the validation layer. If I disable the validation layers the segv happens inside the driver instead.

Comment: "*I am using c# with a binding for the c++ libraries.*" Is any of the code you've shown C#? And if so, which is which language?

Comment: I have added labels now. The last bit is my code

Answer (score 0):

The crash was caused by me passing in the vertex shader module into both the slot for the vertex shader and fragment shader.

```cs
VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo[] shaderStages = new VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo[2];
            shaderStages[0] = VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo.New();
            shaderStages[0].flags = (uint)VkShaderStageFlags.Vertex;
            shaderStages[0].module = vs;
            byte[] vsFuncName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("main" + char.MinValue);
            fixed (byte* ptr = &(vsFuncName[0]))
                shaderStages[0].pName = ptr;

            shaderStages[1] = VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo.New();
            shaderStages[1].flags = (uint)VkShaderStageFlags.Fragment;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            shaderStages[1].module = vs;//This should be fs not vs
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            byte[] fsFuncName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("main" + char.MinValue);
            fixed (byte* ptr = &(fsFuncName[0]))
                shaderStages[1].pName = ptr;

            fixed (VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo* ptr = &(shaderStages[0]))
                pCreateInfo.pStages = ptr;
            pCreateInfo.stageCount = 2;
```